# How can I use a variable created within a function?

Tags: arrays, function, vbscript

I have a function with an array inside:

```
Function newFunction()
  Dim newArray(1,1)
  newArray(0,0) = "1"
  newArray(1,0) = "2"
  newArray(0,1) = "3"
  newArray(1,1) = "4"
  newFunction = newArray
End Function
```

I want to be able to call this function on another page and write the results like this:

```
<%= newFunction(1,0) %>
```

and this should write out: 2

I keep getting the error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" when I do this. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you should actually be doing:

```
<%= newFunction()(1,0) %>
```

But I'm no expert in VB.

Answer (score 1):

You need this instead:

```
<%= newFunction()(1, 0) %>
```

It thinks you're calling `newFunction` with arguments `1` and `0`, not accessing its return value.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with scope. Your "other page" cannot see, or doesn't have access to the definition of this function.

In order to do something like this, you need to include the file that has the definition of this function.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to do this in this manner?  Why not just access the array itself on the second page?